# OpenCV training to detect static image

Tags: opencv

I want to detect the flag of my country. But I have trouble with training. I have one positive sample and 4 negative samples. This is my folder structrue:

```
/negative
   /img
      img1.jpg
      img2.jpg
      img3.jpg
      img4.jpg

/positive
     flag.jpg
```

This is how I call create_samples:

```
opencv_createsamples -img positive/flag.jpg -vec flag.vec
```

But command does not finish and popup windows appears saying that error appeared. This is output of create_samples command:

```
Info file name: (NULL)
Img file name: positive/flag.jpg
Vec file name: flag.vec
BG  file name: (NULL)
Num: 1000
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 80
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Width: 24
Height: 24
Create training samples from single image applying distortions...
```

Can anyone guide me through the process of haar training of static image (1 image) in OpenCV? I am running Windows 7 Ultimate x64

**EDIT**

This works:

```
opencv_createsamples -img positive/flag.jpg -vec flag.vec -num 0
```

I guess the problem is with **-num 0** parameter

Comment: Have you tried with -num 1 param? Also try to provide -w and -h parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Haar is not your best shot at detecting a country's flag , better use color detection

```
COLOR_MIN = np.array([20, 80, 80],np.uint8)
```

COLOR_MAX = np.array([40, 255, 255],np.uint8)
but if you still insist on haar

creating samples :

```
$ <opencv_createsamples> -vec <binary_description> -image <positive_image> -bg <negative_description>
```

Training the cascade :

```
$ <opencv_traincascade> -data <cascade> -vec <binary_description> -bg     <negative_description>
```